# Can we choose how to connect the neurons in tensorflow?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning

My question is :
Can we choose how to connect the neurons in tensorflow ?
Instead of fully connected.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, sure you can do that. I suggest you start with the [Tensorflow Tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/tutorials/mnist/beginners/index.html). Or you can have a look at my [XOR example](https://martin-thoma.com/tf-xor-tutorial/).

Tensorflow lets you define a computational graph which is then automatically optimized by an objective you define and an algorithm you choose. This graph can be a fully connected standard feed forward network or anything else.